# Is it necessary to close connection of a WCF call, when WCF has been hosted in IIS

Tags: c#

As the title implies, i am curious if i need to explicitly close a WCF connection, if WCF is hosted in IIS. Does IIS handle that also automatically.
Thanks

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you open the connection, you are responsible for closing it.  If not, then you probably aren't.

Comment: @Amy Thanks for you answer. See i was thinking the same (IIS should handle that), but after trying a lot the "The connection was not closed" error is not showing up if i wrap a WCF client call in a using statement, whereas without it, the error happens after ~10 calls.

Comment: Perhaps that is pertinent information that would be helpful in fully understanding your problem?  Please edit your question with the code exhibiting the issue.

Comment: I am currently doing some more testing, i'll update if i have some useful infos.

Comment: @Amy I found my answer, thanks much.

Comment: Put your answer **below** and keep the question and answer separate.  You can then accept your answer after a brief time limit has expired and get some rep.

Comment: Exactly haha sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after further investigating of my code, turns out that "The connection was not closed" was not related to WCF at all, but rather inside one of the methods of the service (threading problem). The good thing out of this is that i am now confident that WCF hosted in IIS closes connection automatically.